# How to watch a model for changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

Lets say you have 2 models...

```
Store :has_many products 
Product :belongs_to store
```

..and the `Product` model has the attribute `:price`.

I want to have a view that shows users of updated prices of products if they go down in cost. I'm not sure where to start though. What about if I wanted to give the users the choice of which products to watch? How would you set this up?

Comment: Is it a view in realtime (javascript/ajax) or are you talking about a longer period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with [ActiveRecord Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Observer.html) on your price model to trigger a notification every time a price changes.

You could then fan out these notifications across a list of subscribers. There are a number of solutions for pub/sub frameworks. One is Rails's native built-in Notification API, explained in detail in José Valim's book [Crafting Rails Applications](http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications). Another one is the [Faye gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/faye), take a look at [their site](http://faye.jcoglan.com/).

Other options are EventMachine, Node.js, or Websockets.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is add a field "trend" or something like that, that I would update each time the price changes (with a callback or an observer), and set it to "increase/decrease", or something that has that meaning. Then, I'd look for all the products where the trend is decrease and that were updated (according to updated_at) recently, recently being a value you define, it can be "in the last two weeks", "since user last login", etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ajax with polling.

On the server side I would have a background job (choose from backgroundrb, rescue, cron, etc).
Every polling interval I would see if things have changed and if so show the content.

I would track what changes usng timestamps and comparing to Now().